# How to dynamically remove or replace words with uncertain numbers in a string using R, stringr etc?

Tags: r, regex, replace, cpu-word, stringr

Let's say I have data:

```
s1 <-'aaa'
s2 <- 'bbb'
s <- 'aaa bbb poefaaapeka 111bbbcde'
```

s1 and s2 are two words. I want to remove or replace from s. So the result should be:

```
'poefaaapeka 111bbbcde'
```

Please note that I only delete aaa when it is a word. I need to keep it if it is in another word. In my data, I am not sure how many words every time and what the words are. So I cannot use the operation like pattern='aaa|bbb'. Also, I have to get rid of those words all together, so the pattern should be like:

```
s1|s2|s3...
```

So that I can delete all the words which change all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try building a regex alternation which will target both of the `s1` and `s2` terms for removal:

```
s1 <-'aaa'
s2 <- 'bbb'
regex <- paste0("\\b(?:", s1, "|", s2, ")\\b\\s*")
s <- 'aaa bbb poefaaapeka 111bbbcde'
output <- sub("\\s*$", "", gsub(regex, "", s))

s
output

[1] "aaa bbb poefaaapeka 111bbbcde"
[1] "poefaaapeka 111bbbcde"
```

The regex pattern used here is `\b(?:aaa|bbb)\b\s*`, and note that it also trims any amount of whitespace on the right side of the `aaa` or `bbb` term.  The extra call to `sub` is required should the first term in the input be `aaa` or `bbb`.  It has to do with that we can't trim whitespace on both sides (for fear of concatenating words), so we arbitrarily chose to do it only on the right side.